# Understanding the definition of Hilbert function space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I was reading the Hilbert function spaces from the chapter 2 of [Pick Interpolation and Hilbert Function Spaces by Jim Agler & John E. McCarthy](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-44#). It says the following-

[image]

So by Hilbert function space we mean **the collection of functions from a set $X$ to $H^*$ for some Hilbert space $H$ where $H^*$ denotes the dual of $H$**. Is it correct? Or, I'm misinterpreting the definition?

But this is the definition the Bergman space (in Example 2.2 above) is becoming a Hilbert function space?

Can anybody help me to understand the definition of Hilbert function space? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: ${\cal H}$ contains functions $f:X \to \mathbb{C}$ such that for any $x \in X$ we have $(f \mapsto f(x)) \in {\cal H}^*$. (Note that evaluation at a point is not necessarily defined in an arbitrary Hilbert space.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $\cal H$ is the function space, not the codomain of the functions, that is not precised in the definition.

More formally, $\cal H$ is an Hilbert function space if $\cal H$ is a Hilbert space and
$$
{\cal H} = \{f:X\to Y \,|\, \forall x\in X, (x\mapsto f(x)) \text{ is continuous} \}
$$
for some sets $X$ sand $Y$.

In the case of the example, ${\cal H} = L^2_a(\Bbb D)$, $X = \Bbb D$ and $Y = \Bbb C$.